# Finding function that maximizes ratio of area to length

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I'm new to variational analysis, so I need someone to check, if I'm going in the right direction.

Let's say I need to find a curve $y(x)$ with $y(0) = 1$ and $y(1) = 0$ that maximizes ratio of area (enclosed by a curve and $x$-axis) to length of this curve. In other words, I need to maximize
$$
\int_0^1F(y,y')dx,\text{ where } F(y,y') = \frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}.
$$
Thus Euler-Lagrange equation simplifies to this:
$$
F_y - \frac{d}{dx}F_{y'} = 0,
$$
$$
F_y - F_{yy'}y' - F_{y'y'}y'' = 0,\text{ since }F_{xy'} = 0.
$$
Now multiplying it by $y'$ simplifies to
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(F-y'F_{y'}) = 0,
$$
$$
F-y'F_{y'} = C,C\text{ is constant. }
$$
Plugging our $F(y, y')$ into the last equation gives
$$
\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} - y'\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{2yy'}{\sqrt{(1+y'^2)^3}}\right) = C,
$$
$$
\frac{y(1+y'^2)+yy'^2}{\sqrt{(1+y'^2)^3}} = C,
$$
$$
\frac{2yy'^2 + y}{\sqrt{(1+y'^2)^3}} = C.
$$
Now how to solve this would be my next question, but first I need to know, if variations-wise I'm correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To find maximum area for a given length their ratio is taken as the Lagrange multiplier. (primes are understood as differentiation with respect to x.)

$$ \dfrac{\int y dx}{\int \sqrt{(1+y^{'2} }dx}= \lambda  $$

where we take the constant as ratio of unevaluated indefinite integrals.

We *cannot divide the quantities right under the integral sign*!

Considering object and constraint together we find constrained maximum of

$$ \int(  y- \lambda \sqrt{(1+y^{'2} }) \, dx  $$ where the Lagrangian is:

$$ F(x,y,y^{'}) = (y- \lambda \sqrt{(1+y^{'2} }) $$

This when applied to Euler-Lagrange Equation results in constant curvature circles

$$ y y''/(1+y^{'2})^{3/2} = \lambda $$

The integrand should pass through (0,1) and (1,0), allowing determination of integration constants.

EDIT1:

If you had been  asked hypothetically to find in an unconstrained problem to maximize

$$ \int y(x) \cos\phi\; dx $$

where $ \phi $ is tangent slope then for *that* problem the ODE you found out is correct.